# How to convert .obj to .stl in blender via python script

Tags: python, mesh, export, obj, stl

I want to convert .obj to .stl in blender via python script.Here is my code.

```
import bpy
obj_in = '1b3c286bce219ddb7135fc51795b4038.obj'
stl_out = 'current.stl'
import_obj = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=obj_in)
print(bpy.context.selected_objects)
for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    object.select = True

    bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_out, ascii=False)
```

I run the script in ubuntu16.04 shell, and the error was:

```
(  0.0000 sec |   0.0000 sec) Importing OBJ 
'1b3c286bce219ddb7135fc51795b4038.obj'...

  (  0.0001 sec |   0.0000 sec) Parsing OBJ file...

(  0.0131 sec |   0.0130 sec) Done, loading materials and images...
ProgressMaterial not found MTL: 'model.mtl'

(  0.0137 sec |   0.0136 sec) Done, building geometries (verts:621 faces:1902 materials: 153 smoothgroups:1) ...
(  0.0331 sec |   0.0330 sec) Done.

  (  0.0333 sec |   0.0332 sec) Finished importing: 
'1b3c286bce219ddb7135fc51795b4038.obj'
Progress: 100.00%

[bpy.data.objects['mesh5_mesh5-geometry'], bpy.data.objects['mesh2_mesh2 geometry'], bpy.data.objects['mesh4.002_mesh4-geometry'], bpy.data.objects['mesh4.001_mesh4-geometry'], bpy.data.objects['mesh1_mesh1 geometry'], bpy.data.objects['mesh3.002_mesh3-geometry'], bpy.data.objects['mesh3.001_mesh3-geometry']]

Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data
Error: Object does not have geometry data

Blender quit
```

Is there any correct methods to convert .obj to .stl in blender via python scripts?

Comment: The obj file cames from the 3D shapeNet.

Comment: Do you get the error if you do this manually via the UI?  In your export loop, as well as selecting the object (`ob.select = True`) , also set it to context with `context.scene.objects.active = ob` before calling the operator.  Strongly suggest not using `object` as a variable name as it is a basic python keyword.

Comment: without using python script.
import the .obj file into blender and export the file as .stl
done.

Comment: @ZeminLi I've tested your script and it works well and the stl is exported successfully with no errors. Could you upload your blend files here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can try to help you?